# the build would never end

Tags: c, build, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S814C.png)

I've just started learning C, so I've been practicing some basic codes.
I pressed F7 to initiate the build, but everything I get is the message like this-

```
build started...
===========Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to date, 0 skipped=========
```

I waited for over ten minutes and nothing would happen.
I made a new solution with the exact same code, but then it worked without problem.
what would be the problem...?

Comment: The message **was** the build. The program was already built, so no action was taken. You would either have to change something or clean the project to force it to compile anything.

Comment: but I couldn't find the exe file in my repository file. I also tried pressing F5 or Ctrl+F5, but I got an error message saying that the exe file cannot be found.

Comment: Try a clean build (I think it is `rebuild solution` in VS).

Comment: That won't work too... The rebuild was successful but the debug wouldn't work, followed with the error message that the exe file couldn't be found in the repository file.

Comment: it will work. It cannot be reproduced. Unfortunatelly I do not understand what the message is and if you want to post an image it has to be in English

Comment: Thanks! I changed the image.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you make any changes to your project Properties such as  so that it cannot generate the executable program.

**First**, right-click on your C++ project **Properties**-->**Configuration Properties**-->**General**--> change **Output Directories** to `$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\`.

also change **Intermediate Directories** to `$(Configuration)\`.

change **Target Name** to `$(ProjectName)`.

[image]

**Besides**, enter Linker-->General

change **Output File** to `$(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)`

[image]

**After that**, delete any `Debug` or `Release`,`x64` folder under the solution folder and project folder.

Test it again.

Comment: Everything was fine in the properties setting, so I tried deleting the Debug file and I got an error message in the output window(C:\Users\LG\source\repos\Project8_3\Project8_3\Project8_3.vcxproj : error  : Project "C:\Users\LG\source\repos\Project8_3\Project8_3\Project8_3.vcxproj" could not be found.) Maybe it's just a temporary error in my computer since everything else except this project runs properly...but thank you for your appreciation!! :D

Comment: Did you check your project folder that the `vcxproj` exist? Also, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, did it work?

Comment: I deleted the `Debug` file so the `vcxproj` doesn't exist anymore... therefore I cannot check if erasing the `.vs` file would work.

Comment: Debug folder is the output folder of your project. And `vcxproj` file should be in the project folder. So why your Debug folder contains the `vcxproj` file. That is wrong. And you should make it back in the project folder. The file is the build description file.You cannot build your project without it.